# VBA excel R1C1 formula

Tags: vba, excel

Why doesn't the VBA editor like this function? It runs fine within an excel cell but when I try to incorporate it into a Macro it is flagged as bad syntax.

`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(COUNT(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},LEFT(R2C1,1)))=0,MID(LEFT(R2C1,FIND(' ',R2C1,1)), FIND('.',R2C1,1)+1, FIND(' ',R2C1,1)), LEFT(R2C1,FIND(' ',R2C1,1)))"`

Do I have to escape characters? Like empty quotes or Braces?

Comment: You have to double quote a double quote `""` in VBA code yields `"` in your string, but you don't have any of those. Beyond that, I don't think you'd have to escape any other characters.

Comment: Replace the apostrophes in the formula with ""

Comment: @Rory Yup, that's it. Make that an answer so (s)he can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula needs regular quotes (which you escape by doubling them) not single quotes:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(COUNT(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},LEFT(R2C1,1)))=0,MID(LEFT(R2C1,FIND("" "",R2C1,1)), FIND(""."",R2C1,1)+1, FIND("" "",R2C1,1)), LEFT(R2C1,FIND("" "",R2C1,1)))"
```